# jQuery click depreceated, what alternative should I use

Tags: jquery, click

I am rebuilding a site I built for a client in 2013. When I load the jQuery PHPStorm is telling me that click is depreceated, and that I should use a better alternative. What should I use?

Here is my code

```
let displayUnits = false;

$(function() {
$('.initial').slideDown(1000);
  $('#units').click(function() {
    if (!displayUnits) {
      $('.sUnit').fadeIn(1000);
      $("#units").html('Hide Storage Units');
      displayUnits = true;
      }
    else if (displayUnits) {
      $('.sUnit').fadeOut(1000);
      $("#units").html('Display Storage Units');
      displayUnits = false;
      }
  });
  $('.contact').click(function() {
  $('.sUnit').fadeOut(600);
  $('.initial').slideUp(1500, function() {
  // Call generic function after buttons "slideUp"
  $(location).attr('href', '../contact/');
 });
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change $('#units').click(function() {})

To $('#units').on('click',function() {});

As Máté Safranka pointed out the best reference is JQuery API documentation

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: For future reference, your best bet in such cases is the official API documentation: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @Máté Safranka Thanks for that Mate (I don't have accents on my keyboard) I'll update the answer to include your link